# Is there any way to roll back execution of delete method with ldap3

Tags: django, ldap, openldap, ldap-query, ldap3

I'm using Django 4.1 and ldap3 to connect directory service using ldap. Is there any way to roll back execution of delete method?
the sample code likes below:

```
# import class and constants
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL

# define the server
s = Server('servername', get_info=ALL)  # define an unsecure LDAP server, requesting info on DSE and schema

# define the connection
c = Connection(s, user='user_dn', password='user_password')

# perform the Delete operation
c.delete('cn=user1,ou=users,o=company')

#some checks here
#if condition:
#   user1.recover()
```

after some checking, I want to recover user's data based on a condition.

Thanks!

I've searched about rollback delete execution, but did not find any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When  the object is deleted from the LDAP directory by `delete` method, it's gone permanently.

So in the rollback mechanism:

**First step**: Copy the Object.

**Second Step**: Storing the copy in a temporary location.

**Third Step**: Delete the object. `c.delete('cn=user1,ou=users,o=company')`

Otherwise there is no built in rollback mechanism to restore it once that is deleted  by `delete` method of ldap3.